# Method "GET_DATA_REF" does not exist (cl_salv_bs_runtime_info), why?

Tags: abap

I cannot use `cl_salv_bs_runtime_info=>get_data_ref` as I get this syntax error:

> Method "GET_DATA_REF" does not exist. There is however a method with
>   similar name "GET_DATA"

Maybe I am using a newer or an older version of SAP or is it something else?

My code:

```
REPORT  ZSAM1.

 TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_report,
          rec_acc TYPE skont,
          vendor TYPE LFA1-LIFNR,
          jan_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          jan_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          feb_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          feb_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          mar_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          mar_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          apr_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          apr_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          may_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          may_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          jun_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          jun_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          jul_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          jul_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          aug_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          aug_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          sep_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          sep_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          oct_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          oct_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          nov_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          nov_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          dec_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          dec_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          acc_bal_deb TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
          acc_bal_cred TYPE BSEG-WRBTR,
        END OF ty_report,
        tt_report TYPE TABLE OF ty_report.

DATA:  lt_report TYPE tt_report,
       lv_ukurs type tcurr-ukurs,
       Tcurr1 type tcurr,
       fieldname(4) type c,
       fnamedebit(20) type c,
       fnamecredit(20) type c.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_rep> LIKE LINE OF lt_report.


 select single ukurs from tcurr
        into lv_ukurs
        where fcurr = 'EUR'
        and   tcurr = 'AUD'. "<- your  local currency

DATA: lr_pay_data        TYPE REF TO data,
      lr_pay_data_line   TYPE REF TO data,
      lr_data_descr      TYPE REF TO cl_abap_datadescr,
      lr_data_line_descr TYPE REF TO cl_abap_datadescr.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <lt_pay_data>      TYPE ANY TABLE,
               <ls_pay_data_line> TYPE ANY TABLE.

  cl_salv_bs_runtime_info=>set(
    EXPORTING display  = abap_false
              metadata = abap_false
              structure = ''
              data     = abap_true ).

SUBMIT RFKSLD00 via SELECTION-SCREEN and return.


cl_salv_bs_runtime_info=>get_data_ref(
IMPORTING r_data_descr = lr_data_descr
     r_data_line_descr = lr_data_line_descr ).

CREATE DATA lr_pay_data TYPE HANDLE lr_data_descr.
CREATE DATA lr_pay_data_line TYPE HANDLE lr_data_descr.

ASSIGN lr_pay_data->* TO <lt_pay_data>.
ASSIGN lr_pay_data_line->* TO <ls_pay_data_line>.

cl_salv_bs_runtime_info=>get_data(
  IMPORTING t_data = <lt_pay_data> 
        t_data_line = <ls_pay_data_line> ).

LOOP AT <lt_pay_data> ASSIGNING <ls_pay_data_line>.

 APPEND INITIAL LINE to lt_report ASSIGNING <fs_rep>.
 MOVE-CORRESPONDING <ls_pay_data_line> TO <fs_rep>.

WRITE: / <ls_pay_data_line>.

ENDLOOP.

Write: 'Program End!'.
```

Comment: The syntax error tells you something and if you look at the concerned class you see nothing, then of course it means that it doesn't exist in your system. Note that this class is not officially supported. Use it at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error tells you that the method doesn't exist. If you look at the concerned class and you don't see that method, then of course it means that it doesn't exist in your system.

Software keep evolving. In new versions there are sometimes new programs, sometimes others are deleted. That's life...

PS: note that the class `cl_salv_bs_runtime_info` is not officially supported. Use it at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently stumble upon the same problem.

This error is caused by cl_salv_bs_runtime_info version don't have method GET_DATA_REF.

> You might want to try to read this article
>   https://blogs.sap.com/2011/07/07/gain-programmatic-access-to-data-of-sapgui-alv-reports/
>   .

In the near end article they describe the difference between get_data_ref and get_data. Since we do not have get_data_ref, if we want to retrieve alv data from submit program we can only use get_data report. You might have notice that in this version there is parameter structure in

> cl_salv_bs_runtime_info=>set(
>       EXPORTING display  = abap_false
>                 metadata = abap_false
>                 structure = ''
>                 data     = abap_true ).

This is because method get_data can not be used for dynamic table. Before retrieving the data we need to know its structure first. Since you want to submit standard program RFKSLD00, you can first search for the structure used in them. After finding the structure you can put the structure name in structure parameter.

After that, you can declare an internal table using the structure submitted above and put the internal table in to t_data parameter in get_data method.

Hope this answer will help.